# C# await in Windows service becomes very slow

Tags: c#, iis, service

Our program use the Orleans frame and we package it as a Windows service. But when I use one method which has await tag, the await result will use a lot of time (await method just uses 50 ms, but get the result will use 20s). My english is poor, so forgive me and help me please!

This is my code

https://i.stack.imgur.com/LliT0.png

```
MOperDetail myOper = await service.GetOneOper(ZTID, CurrElyID);
```

Comment: Don't post pictures of code, post code as properly formatted text. Also use the correct tags. C is not C#.

Comment: sry this is my first time publish a question

Comment: The 20s are used within the method itself. Guessing from the picture the query takes such  a long time. Either the query is poorly written and needs so much time or the server is slow.

Comment: the sql  we test  just use a little time,and there is no problem  in ourself computer  but in the test comoputer  it will become slow

Comment: Output log messages with timestamp within the method to find out where the time is taken.

Comment: does cors request can  influence the async method?

Comment: You need a profiler to tell what takes that long to finish. Merely this function call itself is useless.

Comment: Might be a partial deadlock due to lack of `await`

Comment: Probably caused by a slow DB server, untuned query or slow network. How much data is transfered?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.